# In SilverStripe 4, how to extend an existing method when there is no Extension Hook inside the original method?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I want to override 'loginForm' method in 'LoginHandler' class. I am trying to use the code given below for that. But it is not working.

LoginHandlerExtension.php

```
    <?php

    use SilverStripe\Core\Extension;

    class LoginHandlerExtension extends Extension {

        public function loginForm() {
            return 'xxxxxx';
        }
    }
```

app.yml

```
SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler:
  extensions:
    - LoginHandlerExtension
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would you want to override on the loginForm method? If you want it to use a different Form class (e.g. `MyMemberLoginForm`), you can tell Injector to use your custom class in YML like this:

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  MemberLoginForm:
    class: My\Namespaced\LoginForm
```

as the LoginForm method does nothing else but return the form.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I should have used an Injector.