# How to redirect a member to a specific page once they have logged in depending on what group they are in?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am wanting to have 2x different types of Members. I have created 2x different groups as per below. Each group will redirect to a specific page once they are logged in.

- Resellers -> redirect to `website.com/resellers`
- Architects -> redirect to `website.com/architects`

These members once logged in will only be able to see this page which will just be a front end page with a list of PDF's.

I have started by hooking into the: `afterMemberLoggedIn()` method.

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
use SilverStripe\Security\Security;

class MemberExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function afterMemberLoggedIn()
    {
       if (Security::getCurrentUser()->inGroup('Reseller')) {
           // Redirect to reseller page
       }
    }

}
```

app.yml:

```
SilverStripe\Security\Member:
  extensions:
    - MemberExtension
```

I have a feeling this isn't the correct way to go about it? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I am stuck on this - have posted a similar question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608628/silverstripe-4-member-login-and-redirect-to-specific-page

Did you end up with a solution for this? Are you able to share what direction you took if so? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is code that I've used on SS3 projects. You could convert it to SS4. It was based on a post on ssbits from years ago.

Basically what happens is you extend group with 2 fields. One is a checkbox for redirecting to the admin which you will set for the administrator group, and the other field **LinkPage** allows you to select a page to redirect to on successful login. This will be set for the resellers and architects groups.

**mysite/_config/extensions.yml**

```
---
name: 'mysiteextensions'
---
Group:
  extensions:
    - 'GroupDecorator'

Injector:
  MemberLoginForm:
    MysiteLoginForm
```

**mysite/extensions/GroupDecorator.php**

```
class GroupDecorator extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'GoToAdmin' => 'Boolean'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'LinkPage' => 'SiteTree'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Members', CheckboxField::create('GoToAdmin', 'Go to admin?'), 'Members');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Members', TreeDropdownField::create('LinkPageID', 'Or select a page to redirect to', 'SiteTree'), 'Members');
    }

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**mysite/extensions/MysiteLoginForm.php**

```
class MysiteLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm {

    public function dologin($data) {
        if ($this->performLogin($data)) {
            if (!$this->redirectByGroup($data)) {
                $this->controller->redirect(Director::baseURL());
            }
        } else {
            if ($badLoginURL = Session::get('BadLoginURL')) {
                $this->controller->redirect($badLoginURL);
            } else {
                //Director::redirectBack();

                //if we redirect to the admin after a failed login, it will show us the login form.
                $this->controller->redirect(Director::baseURL().'admin');
            }
        }
    }

    public function redirectByGroup($data) {

        //gets current member which is logged in.
        $member = Member::currentUser();

        //gets all groups
        $groups = DataObject::get('Group');

        $backURL = Controller::curr()->getRequest()->getVar('BackURL');

        //cycle through the groups
        foreach ($groups as $group) {

            //if member is in the group and the group has gotoAdmin checked
            if ($member->inGroup($group->ID) && $group->GoToAdmin == 1) {

                //redirect to the admin page.
                $this->controller->redirect(Director::baseURL().'admin');
                return true;

                //member is in the group and the group has a page link defined.
            } elseif ($member->inGroup($group->ID) && $group->LinkPageID != 0) {
                //get the page.
                $link = DataObject::get_by_id('SiteTree', $group->LinkPageID)->URLSegment;

                //redirect to page
                $this->controller->redirect(Director::baseURL() . $link);

                return true;
            }
        }
        //not found.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code I appreciate it. I have converted the code over to SS4, just abit stuck on how to hook the custom form extension in SS4 in the .yml file, are you able to help with this?

Comment: @ifusion Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247389/in-silverstripe-4-how-to-extend-an-existing-method-when-there-is-no-extension-h

Comment: thanks, had a look at that but seem to be missing something, this is what I have atm: https://kopy.io/Kj5ES - looks like the `_contruct` needs something awell?