# Silverstripe 4: Member Login and Redirect to specific page

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'd like to redirect Members who have successfully logged in to specific pages based on the group to which they belong.

In the past I've been able to do this in SS3 with the following:

**CustomLoginForm.php:**

```
class CustomLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm
{

    public function dologin($data)
    {
        // Redirect functionality here
    }
}
```

**/mysite/_config.yml:**

```
Injector:
  MemberLoginForm:
    class: CustomLoginForm
```

However, this approach does not work Silverstripe 4.

I have tried:

- As above, creating a **CustomLoginForm** that extends **MemberLoginForm**, defining `doLogin()` and applying it with Injector
- Creating a **CustomLoginHandler** that extends **LoginHander**, defining `redirectAfterSuccessfulLogin()` and applying this with Injector

Neither of these methods have worked.

I'm stuck with how to approach this on SS4, and would appreciate any guidance!

Comment: As you have answered this yourself, I assume you "accept it"?  If so please accept it.

Comment: Is there a way you can check if the user is an admin role and if so, keep the redirect to /admin

Answer (score 4):

Have resolved this using the following approach:

**CustomLoginHander.php**:

```
<?php

namespace MySite\Namespace\Extensions;

use SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler;
use SilverStripe\Security\Security;

class CustomLoginHandler extends LoginHandler
{

    protected function redirectAfterSuccessfulLogin()
    {
        // Login redirect methods
    }
}
```

**mysite.yml:**

```
---
Name: myproject
---
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Security\MemberAuthenticator\LoginHandler:
    class: MySite\Namespace\Extensions\CustomLoginHandler
```